# S.O.L.I.D Principle - Clarification

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Open/Closed Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016/the-open-closed-principle)

I can understand that Open/Close principle suggests that

```
"You should be able to extend the class behaviour, without modifying it"
```

What does here open and close mean?

Comment: Just guessing... open to extension, closed to modifying

Comment: Really good article: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/chad_myers/archive/2008/03/07/pablo-s-topic-of-the-month-march-solid-principles.aspx

Comment: I think the reason it isn't a total duplicate is because it's really a question about the English language words as used in this context.  The words are chosen to appear contradictory, making it hard to parse the meaning.

Comment: @Justin Williams :The article you referred is very good to read,thank you very much for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open to extension.

Closed against update/change/modification.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle

It's pretty clear in the wikipedia article.