# Serialize Jaxb Pojos to multiple or different namespaces

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

Consider the following code:

```
Main.java
====
package com.sample;

import com.sample.entity.Customer;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Main {    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
       JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

       Customer customer = new Customer();
       customer.setId(123);

       Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
       m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
       m.marshal(customer, System.out);    
    }
}


Customer.java
====
package com.sample.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

package-info.java
====
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.org/package", elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.sample.entity;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
```

I wish to reuse the Customer POJO and create two different namespace values. So first I wish to print the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer xmlns="http://www.example.org/package">
    <id>123</id>
</customer>
```

like the current code does, then create a second xml with a different main namespace from the same pojo that will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer xmlns="http://www.another.org/package">
    <id>123</id>
</customer>
```

or remove the namespace all together

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <id>123</id>
</customer>
```

Comment: You should make an extra code snippet for the *@XmlSchema* part as it is very relevant, but can easily be overlooked.

Answer (score 7):

This is a good question.

Instead of working on the type-level you could work on the Jaxb node level.
There is almost no overhead involved.

The key is creating/accessing `JAXBElement` (node level elements) out of your business logic classes and customize the XML-Node it represents with an according `QName` definition.

`QName` provides several options for customization, ranging from fully qualified namespaces to no namespace at all. The only caveat is that using a namespace without prefix is not possible.  Jaxb will use a default namespace if you don't provide one.

**Example**:

```
QName elaborateQName = new QName("http://www.another.org/package", "customer", "myNs");
QName simpleQName = new QName("customer");

JAXBElement jx1 = new JAXBElement(elaborateQName, customer.getClass(), customer);
JAXBElement jx2 = new JAXBElement(simpleQName, customer.getClass(), customer);

m.marshal(jx1, System.out);
m.marshal(jx2, System.out);
```

This will produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<myNs:customer xmlns:myNs="http://www.another.org/package">
    <id>123</id>
</myNs:customer>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <id>123</id>
</customer>
```

Using a namespace without prefix is not possible. Trying a QName with empty *prefix* or the equivalent [`XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX) as parameter will result in a default prefix (like *ns1*)  being generated:

```
 // QName defaultNs = new QName("http://www.another.org/package", "customer", "");

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:customer xmlns:ns1="http://www.another.org/package">
    <id>123</id>
</ns2:customer>
```

Using *null* as the parameter for `prefix`yields an Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix cannot be "null" when creating a QName
at javax.xml.namespace.QName.<init>(QName.java:251)
```

Comment: package-info.java is inside the example, it's autogenerated by jaxb tools

Comment: If you have influence on your JAXB generation process you could try skipping package-info.java generation at all (via xjc's -npa option)

Answer (score 3):

**How to override the root xmlns attribute with MOXy:**

[EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) provides easy customization of JAXB marshalling, including changing the default namespace of your root element.  The Object to XML mapping (*OXM*) for overriding the default namespace is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" version="2.5">
    <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" namespace="http://www.another.org/package"/>
</xml-bindings>
```

To have no default namespace, use `<xml-schema element-form-default="UNSET"/>` instead.

**MOXy Setup:**

1) add the library to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Add a `jaxb.properties` to your object model package to enable MOXy's factory (*e.g.* `src/main/resources/com/sample/entity/jaxb.properties`):

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

3) Instantiate your context according to your OXM configuration (*in this example, the OXM file is at* `src/main/resources/com/sample/entity/my-oxm.xml`):

```
Map<String, Source> metadata = Collections.singletonMap("com.sample.entity", new StreamSource(Customer.class.getResourceAsStream("my-oxm.xml")));
Map<String, Object> properties = Collections.singletonMap(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, metadata);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {customer.getClass()}, properties);
```

You can then use marshalling on the `JAXBContext` as normal.  Instantiate separate contexts for each different OXM file you want to use.

**Additional customizations with MOXy:**

Using MOXy allows you to further customize the marshalling of your entity in the future without changing your object model, effectively making your marshalling logic adhere to the [open/closed principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59016/2646526) even though you have no explicit `Marshaller` classes.  For instance, if you needed to marshal your `Customer` object as a `Person`, you could do this by adding another OXM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm" version="2.5">
    <xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" namespace="http://www.example.com/person"/>
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="com.sample.entity.Customer">
            <xml-root-element name="person"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-attribute java-attribute="id" name="personId"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id" xml-path="someOtherId/text()"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```