# How can I write an interface for a place where I obviously can have abstact class but I need an interface?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, interface, refactoring

I have an abstract class that is extended by a final class with very closed implementation(private fields, methods, security oriented).
There is a switch-case that depending on some input chooses which constructor to use.
I want to get rid of the extended class but leave some interface for people to plugin their own implementation.
Any suggestions how to approach this design/OOP problem?

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to "I want to make a thing, but I want the concept of which actual class we should make to be abstracted" is **factories**.

The name of factories has unfortunately been besmirched by louts claiming the cliched 'haha java sucks - look at all them factories!'. Ignore them. They simply haven't run into the scenario of needing to abstract class-wide concepts (constructors and static methods). Because factories are exactly that abstraction.

Trivial example:

```java
public List<Integer> countTo10(Supplier<List<Integer>> factory) {
  List<Integer> list = factory.supply();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) list.add(i);
  return list;
}
```

You can use this method to make a linked list with 1 through 10, or an ArrayList:

```
List<Integer> iAmAnArrayList = countTo10(ArrayList::new);
List<Integer> iAmALinkedList = countTo10(LinkedList::new);
```

With some generics wizardry, you can even make `countTo10`'s return type be the actual thing your factory makes:

```
public <T extends List<Integer>> T countTo10(Supplier<? extends T> factory) {
  T list = factory.supply();
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) list.add(i);
  return list;
}

// can be used as:

ArrayList<Integer> list = countTo10(ArrayList::new);
```

Sometimes `java.util.function.Supplier` as I used in these snippets is insufficient. For example: You want to abstract more than just 'make me one' about a type. Perhaps each implementation comes with a description for use in GUIs, and the factory contains both a method that makes a new one as well as a method that returns a description for the entire class, for example. The concept extends just as easily to 'abstracting static methods'.

In such cases, make your own interface or class for the factory.

**Important note about security**

> private fields, methods, security oriented

It sounds like you're confused. `private` does absolutely nothing for security at all. Or, I surely hope it doesn't: If you run untrusted code on a JVM, trusting that 'they cannot invoke private methods' is a big mistake. Malicious code can invoke those just fine, generally. `private` is about communicating that future versions of the library/app may change what this does, or it may disappear entirely. It was never meant for consumption by anything outside of this source file, and as a consequence, all relevant tooling (javac, your IDE, your build tool, javadoc, etcetera) should act as if this does not exist. Also, the method is effectively `final` for all optimization purposes as it cannot be overridden.

That's what `private` does. *not* 'add security'.

The problem with security stuff is: If you mess it up, usually you won't have a test or other system that tells you so. You won't really know until all heck breaks loose as you or a customer gets hacked. You're steering on pentests, best practices, and experience. Hence, I thought: I'll share some experience, maybe it will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response!While I understand factories I am still not sure how to apply this to my case. I still need the parent classv with minimal to no changes to it. I need to provide an interface for its extended final class so that people can use their own implementations but still they should be extending the parent one in a way if they want those to work. How should I apply what you said?
Also, about security - thanks for mentioning it. I meant actually that there are security stuff going on there, not that I consider private to add security. Bad wording on my end

Comment: Then your question doesn't even begin to include enough information to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have base class and other users should have a possibility to extend behavior of base class. Then we can use strategy pattern combined with factory of objects.
Let me show an example with C# (this code can be easily converted to Java as I did not use any special features of C#).

Let's say we want to build a calculator. So our base class will be `Operation`. Some users wants to add their behavior through adding new class. So it is okay as we keep to [Open Closed principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016/what-is-the-meaning-and-reasoning-behind-the-open-closed-principle).

So our base class `Operation` will look like this:

```
public abstract class Operation
{
    public abstract int Exec(int a, int b);
}
```

and its concrete implementations:

```
public class DivideOperation : Operation
{
    public override int Exec(int a, int b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }
}   

public class MinusOperation : Operation
{
    public override int Exec(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}

public class MultiplyOperation : Operation
{
    public override int Exec(int a, int b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

Then we want to have factory that will return instance of concrete implementation of `Operation` class. How can we map concrete implementation to operation?
We can use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in `C#` or in Java `Map<TKey, TValue> map = new HashMap<TKey, TValue>()`. `TKey` would be enum with operation name:

```
public enum Operator
{
    Plus,
    Minus,
    Divide,
    Multiply
}
```

and factory which maps operator to operations:

```
public class OperationToOperator
{
    public Dictionary<Operator, Operation> OperationByOperator = 
        new Dictionary<Operator, Operation>
    {
        { Operator.Plus, new SumOperation() },
        { Operator.Minus, new MinusOperation() },
        { Operator.Divide, new DivideOperation() },
        { Operator.Multiply, new MultiplyOperation() },
    };
}
```

and our calculator with [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539/what-is-the-dependency-inversion-principle-and-why-is-it-important):

```
public class CalculatorWithDependencyInversionPrinciple
{
    public int Exec(Operation operation, int a, int b)
    {
        return operation.Exec(a, b);
    }
}
```

And this auxiliary class to solve mathematic problem:

```
public class Problem
{
    public Operator Operator { get; private set; }

    public int A { get; private set; }

    public int B { get; private set; }


    public Problem(Operator operato, int a, int b)
    {
        Operator = operato;
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

And our code can be run like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Problem> conditions = new List<Problem>
    {
        new Problem(Operator.Plus, 1, 2),
        new Problem(Operator.Minus, 4, 3),
        new Problem(Operator.Multiply, 5, 6),
        new Problem(Operator.Divide, 8, 2),
    };

    OperationToOperator operationToOperator = new OperationToOperator();
    CalculatorWithDependencyInversionPrinciple calculatorWithDependencyInversionPrinciple = 
        new CalculatorWithDependencyInversionPrinciple();

    foreach (Problem condition in conditions)
        Console.WriteLine
        (
            calculatorWithDependencyInversionPrinciple.Exec
            (
                operationToOperator.OperationByOperator[condition.Operator], 
                condition.A, 
                condition.B
            )
        );
}
```

So we've created simple classes that are testable and we used Strategy pattern.